# Creating project, project creation failed visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

## Problem

I am trying to make a C++ project. I click New Project... > Select Visual C++ from templates > Win32 Console Application > click ok. Then a little error message pops up at the bottom of the screen like this:

[image: 1]

It does not matter what template I pick. Same thing happens if I choose an empty project.

## What I have tried

I first encountered the problem after downloading Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. I then tried repairing it. Same problem. I then uninstalled and reinstalled and got the same problem. I then uninstalled and installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition. Still same problem. Then I uninstalled that I installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition. Still same problem. I am all out of ideas of ways to debug or try to fix this.

All I am going off of is that little error message at the bottom of the screen. I don't know if there are error logs somewhere in Visual Studio, so I can get a better understanding of why the project creation is failing. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

I currently have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition installed

Comment: You can try the solution [here](http://superuser.com/questions/740142/visual-studio-2012-project-creation-failed)

Comment: I tried that and I got an error message typing in the command on step 11 (regsvr32.exe vswizard.dll)

Comment: The module "vswizard.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80070005.

Comment: That seems to be an permission issue. Make sure you're running `cmd` as admin. If your are, try the solution [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/71037d62-d842-44a3-86df-6ed74df6fc39/0x80070005-error-trying-to-register-dll)

Comment: Ok I ran cmd as admin and it ran successfully. I completed all the steps and I reopened Visual Studio, but I am getting the same problem.

Comment: You can enable Visual Studio logging by opening `run`, type `Devenv.exe /log <log path>`. The  log files will be generated in <log path>.

Comment: I tried running `Devenv.exe /log C:/dump` where the C:/dump folder exists and it gave me an error saying The operation could not be completed. No such interface supported.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by installing CMake believe it or not. CMake installer found the pending McAffe installation for the user SYSTEM (whatever it means) and undo installation for SYSTEM. After that the problem was fixed. The bottom line the issue is might be anti-virus in your computer